# singularity and degeneracy of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, singularity-theory

I have trouble distinguishing the difference of singularity and degeneracy in the context of ODE theory. Could anyone give me a couple of examples in illustrating the difference of singular point and the point of degeneracy of an ODE?

Answer (score 1):

If you have $P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0$ then it has a singularity when $\frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$ and $\frac{R(x)}{P(x)}$ are not defined

May be there is a simple and single definition for Degeneracy but i am not aware or able to word what i know properly hopefully the following helps.

Degeneracy is a more complicated depending on equation i would say there are multiple interpretations but generally the most basic one when you have a repeating root for a characteristic equation of homogeneous part of ODE you have degeneracy since the solutions are not linearly dependent so to avoid this and we look for linearly independent solution.

for example if the root $r$ is repeated $k$ times then we generally look for solutions of the form $A_1e^{rx}+A_2 xe^{rx} +A_3 x^2 e^{rx}+....+A_n x^{n-1} e^{rx}$ as these may be linearly independent again if some of these are dependent you need to keep on increasing powers until you get a set of $k$ linearly independent solutions.

Even if we don't have repeated roots our homogenous solutions might be the same as the non-homogenous part which causes us problems so again we say we have a degenerate case.

Also when you draw phase planes for this ODE we usually call this root as Degenerate Stable/unstable node.

If we have a system of equations if the Jacobean is zero then we say its a degenerate system.

Comment: To me, the word degeneracy means the DE vanished at some certain points. I'm thinking about singular boundary value problems. Very often, the odes are nonlinear, non-autonomous and have both points of singularity and degeneracy. In these cases it is hard to do phase plane analysis like what you suggested...would be great if there are some references for studying degenerate ode, and/or alternative methods to find degenerate points.

Comment: @math101  I am not sure if you are talking here about a PDE or a ODE it would be great to help if you can tell me which book and which problem or which theorem you are stuck on may be i can answer better